# how to submit json file in sencha touch in http post multipart?

Tags: sencha-touch

I want to submit json file form **sencha touch** to my tomcat server using http post **multipart** but          i don't    know how to do ?
 can any one give me some idea or example.
Thanks

Comment: Till now, what have u tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do this using jQuery.

```
var request = new FormData();                   
$.each(context.prototype.fileData, function(i, obj) { request.append(i, obj.value.files[0]); });    
request.append('action', 'upload');
request.append('id', response.obj.id);
$.ajax({

    type        : 'POST',
    url     : context.controller,
    data        : request,
    processData : false,
    contentType : false,                        
    success     : function(r) {
        console.log(r);
        //if (errors != null) { } else context.close();

    },

    error       : function(r) { alert('jQuery Error'); }

});
```